# testing result of $.post with json_encode

Tags: javascript, post

I hope someone can help me.

I have this JavaScript code:

```
$.post(url, { 'ids[]': row_ids },function(response)
```

for information post execute this:

```
echo json_encode(array('success'=>true,'message'=>$this->lang->line('items_successful_deleted')));
```

When I debug I found that the response contains this :

```
"Array( [0] => 4555){"success":true,"message":"Vous avez supprim\u00e9 avec succ\u00e8s"}"
```

I just want to test if `success` equal `true` but when I do it like this:

```
if(response.success === true)
```

it doesn't work.

I just want to know how to access the values of the response.

Comment: Have you marked the request as Json????, maybe the intelligent guest is not working. (dataType = "json")

Comment: yes i did try it but it doesn t work

Comment: where is `Array( [0] => 4555)` coming from - that makes it **not** JSON - your server side must be outputting more than you think